# Server 2008 GPO To Use Small Taskbar Icons

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I'm using SBS 2011 for Group Policy on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server used as a terminal server.

Does anyone know a way to set through Group Policy to 'Use Small Icons' in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of settings from [this Azure application](http://gps.cloudapp.net/).  You could set the settings you want in the default profile then lock them down ( User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and taskbar\  Prevent changes to taskbar and Start Menu Settings)  but I do not see a way to specifically set the icon size.

Comment: Very cool interface.  I've been using [the excel spreadsheet](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25250).

Answer (score 1):

The key that is changed is as follows:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\` `reg_dword` `TaskbarSmallIcons`

Setting this to a value of `0x1` will force the taskbar icons to be small.

You can set this value via a GPO by navigating to the Preferences for Registry (`Policy root\User Configuration\Preferences\Windows Settings\Registry`) and creating a new value.